# Redux Form -> Autofocus first input

Tags: forms, redux, autofocus

I have component in Redux-Form, I need an autoFocus on

Now it's doesn't working. What should i do for everytime autofocus first input?

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
  <div>
    <div className ="group">
      <input className="text"
      {...input}
      type={type}/>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <span className="highlight"></span>
      <span className="bar"></span>
      {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
)


  <Field name="name"
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="Username"
    autoFocus
    require/>

  <Field name="email"
   type="email"
    component={renderField}
     label="Email"
    require/>
```

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: No, i tried add autofocus as props, but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autoFocus` does not get placed into the `input`  group. We need to manually handle this.

The only keys that get into `input` are:

```
export type InputProps = {
  checked?: boolean,
  name: string,
  onBlur: { (eventOrValue: Event | any): void },
  onChange: { (eventOrValue: Event | any): void },
  onDrop: { (event: Event): void },
  onDragStart: { (event: Event): void },
  onFocus: { (event: Event): void },
  value: any
}
```

As seen in the source code - https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/FieldProps.types.js.flow#L29-L38

Also seen in the docs - https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/field.md/#input-props

So we would modify our `renderField` to handle all other props and pass it to the `input` like this:

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error, warning }, custom, ...inputProps }) => (
  <div>
    <div className ="group">
      <input className="text" {...input} {...inputProps} />
      <label>{label}</label>
      <span className="highlight"></span>
      <span className="bar"></span>
      {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Notice the change, it is now `<input className="text" {...input} {...inputProps} />`.

I added `custom` to the destructure so that it gets removed as this is what is in `FieldProps` - https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/FieldProps.types.js.flow#L40-L63